# useQuery to conditionally render data

Tags: reactjs, jsx, apollo, react-apollo

I'm attempting to use `useQuery` to `GET` data from my database and then render the data in my REACT component but I keep getting a length undefined error from my JSX. Could anyone look at tell me if my use of `useQuery` is incorrect?

```
const SavedBooks = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_ME);
  console.log(loading)
  console.log(data?.me)
  if (loading) {
    return <h2>LOADING...</h2>
  } else {
    setUserData(data?.me);
  }

  // create function that accepts the book's mongo _id value as param and deletes the book from the database
  const handleDeleteBook = async (bookId) => {
    const token = Auth.loggedIn() ? Auth.getToken() : null;

    if (!token) {
      return false;
    }

    try {
      const response = await deleteBook(bookId, token);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('something went wrong!');
      }

      const updatedUser = await response.json();
      setUserData(updatedUser);
      // upon success, remove book's id from localStorage
      removeBookId(bookId);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
        <>
          <Jumbotron fluid className='text-light bg-dark'>
            <Container>
              <h1>Viewing saved books!</h1>
            </Container>
          </Jumbotron>
            <Container>
              <h2>
                  {userData?.savedBooks.length
                    ? `Viewing ${userData.savedBooks.length} saved ${userData.savedBooks.length === 1 ? 'book' : 'books'}:`
                    : 'You have no saved books!'}
              </h2>
              <CardColumns>
                {userData?.savedBooks.map((book) => {
                  return (
                    <Card key={book.bookId} border='dark'>
                      {book.image ? <Card.Img src={book.image} alt={`The cover for ${book.title}`} variant='top' /> : null}
                      <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{book.title}</Card.Title>
                        <p className='small'>Authors: {book.authors}</p>
                        <Card.Text>{book.description}</Card.Text>
                        <Button className='btn-block btn-danger' onClick={() => handleDeleteBook(book.bookId)}>
                          Delete this Book!
                        </Button>
                      </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                  )
                })}
              </CardColumns>
            </Container>
        </>
  );
};
```

The data will eventually log itself in the console but it doesn't hold up my JSX from rending so I end up with a  `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` around this area:

```
              <h2>
                  {userData?.savedBooks.length
                    ? `Viewing ${userData.savedBooks.length} saved ${userData.savedBooks.length === 1 ? 'book' : 'books'}:`
                    : 'You have no saved books!'}
              </h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happened because at some point `savedBooks` = `undifiend`
So all you need to do is to check if it's, just by adding another `?`

`userData?.savedBooks?.length`

```js
<h2>
  {loading ? 'LOADING...' : 
    userData?.savedBooks?.length ? 
    `Viewing ${userData.savedBooks.length} saved ${userData.savedBooks.length === 1 ? 'book' : 'books'}:`
    : 'You have no saved books!'}
</h2>
```

There is also something in the code that may cause you a problem
You shouldn't use the `setUserData` inside the functional component body directly it will cause unnecessary retenders or enter an infinite render loop.

I would suggest doing something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setUserData(data?.me);
}, [data]);
```

That will make the component render only when the `data` change.

Comment: Adding in that extra optional chaining and ternary definitely solved the problem. I really appreciate the assistance on this one!